# Which optimization packages exist for Python for timetabling?

Tags: python, optimization

I am developing a timetabling application which takes into considerations like:

1. preferred hours for subjects and teachers
2. minimizing the number of hours per day
3. compulsory but abstract rules: "do not take back to back hours", "A teacher with 'HOD' or 'asst prof' tag must be present in 3 of these 5 hours"

---

I loved Drools as it can solve problems with many optimizations algorithms and allows declarative rules.

However, it is in Java and I prefer something that is natively Python.

---

What Python package can help with solving my timetabling problem?

Answer (score 1):

Drools has a Python semantic module that allows to use the Python scripting language to specify rules in our DRL files. I'm not sure if it will help you, but this is the URL that points to more information on it.

http://legacy.drools.codehaus.org/Python+Semantic+Module

Because the URL has the "legacy" string in it, the Python semantic module may not be supported in the latest version of Drools.

EDIT: This solution uses the Jython interpreter.